# How to set the width of a button in a stack view

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uibutton, uistackview

Hey guys I am trying to set the width of a button programmatically using NSLayoutConstraints.

Here is my button:

```
private let testBtn: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    button.setTitle("Test", for: .normal)
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 28)
    button.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
    button.backgroundColor = .red

    return button
}()
```

Here is where I set up the stack view and its constraints:

```
fileprivate func setupButton() {
        let ButtonStackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [ViewBtn])
        ButtonStackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(ButtonStackView)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            ButtonStackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: -100),
            ButtonStackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor),
            ButtonStackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor),
            ButtonStackView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50)
        ])
    }
```

How can I adjust the width of the button and set it to be a rounded button?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can add width constrait to testButton

```
 testBtn.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
```

to round corners you use

```
testBtn.layer.cornerRadius = testBtn.bounds.maxY/2
```

Note: round corners in `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`

Comment: Thank you so much for your help again! when I run that, I get Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints. is this because of other constraints on the page?

Comment: yes ... how many views this stack is having other than this button ?

Comment: dont add trailing or leading anchor to stack view ..... either you can have leading ... or trailing ... as stack view width will be decided by the button width

Comment: ah perfect! that sets the width perfectly! one last question, how do I center the button now?

Comment: you need to center stack view instead of button sir

Comment: remove leading and trailing from stack and give it `ButtonStackView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor)`

Comment: You are a legend! Sorry for wrecking your head! Thank you!